# Closing a tab without closing the window

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Hi I have set up a task in my task scheduler to login to my UTM by opening a firefox window at regular intervals. When the relevant URL is loaded a auto-login GM script works on it and logs me in to UTM.

I would like to close that tab after the login is done. If I use

window.close();

It works fine but if no other tab is opened at the time, it simply closes the window.

Without going into details of UTM I would like the following -

A GM hack which closes the tab only if other tabs are already open. If it is the last tab of the window, then it should just replace it with a blank tab (so that window is not closed).

Probably GM cannot obtain any info about the other tabs, but is there any hack ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this isn't possible, if nothing else then for security reasons: you don't spam javascript from your video streaming tab collecting all your data and submitting forms on your behalf.

[Here's a thread with a solution that worked for IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser) that you may be able to manipulate but as I said it's not likely.

If you decide to have ago, don't think about identifying the number of tabs, it won't happen, instead focus on determining whether or not there are multiple tabs.

The linked example uses    if(clientY == 0)    to determine whether or not the browser is closing. This would be a good starting point.

Again, for security reasons, you won't be able to find out information about open tabs.

Comment: hmmm i ve given up on this. will try to rectify with something other than greasemonkey ... Thanks for your response